# Error executing DDL "drop table Player if exists" via JDBC Statement

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp, orm

Creating a spring mvc  project with database using java configuration . The application gives error for tables operation like create, drop, alter operation for every model class

```
[model class java configuration for web.xml beans.xml dispatcher-servlet][1] -

GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : **Error executing DDL "drop table Player if exists" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table Player if exists" via JDBC Statement**
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615) ~[spring-orm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599) ~[spring-orm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4688) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.34]
**Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists' at line 1**
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    ... 58 common frames omitted


GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : **Error executing DDL "drop table TEAMS if exists" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table TEAMS if exists" via JDBC Statement**
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615) ~[spring-orm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599) ~[spring-orm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4688) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.34]
**Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]**
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:175) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add your code as a text.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Player;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEAMS;
```

Tip: Avoid lowercase uppercase mixing for DB names and column names.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your modules 'application.propeties' file:

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update